# Not able to upload aar using gradle-bintray-plugin: only jar file is uploaded

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, bintray

Using the recommendations from [here](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) I'm not able to upload my android aar to my Bintray account. I got 'Build successfull' using `gradlew bintrayUpload`, but only jar file and a pom file are visible in bintray.
Here is my top level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId 'com.android.me.mylibrary'
            artifactId 'demo-lib'
            version '1.0.1'     
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
bintray {
    user = user
    key = key
    publications = ['MyPublication'] //When uploading Maven-based publication files
    //configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = repo
        name = 'demo-lib'
        userOrg = userorg
        labels = ['aar', 'android', 'example']
        version {
            name = '1.0.1'
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Is there something missing?
I've also try to use the example script [here](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/blob/master/gradle-aar-example/build.gradle) but the result is the same.
Best regards...

Answer (score 0):

yes there is actually something missing. You do not upload the artifact. You upload artifactId but not artifact.

Because there are a lot of outdated tutorials I have actually made a post in [here](https://medium.com/@kostasdrakonakis/how-to-distribute-your-own-android-library-through-jitpack-or-jcenter-and-maven-central-from-174c356e818a) about this. What you need to do also is follow maven specifications for pom.xml and I see that you do not.

In version 4 they require as well those:

```
        pom.withXml {
            def root = asNode()
            root.appendNode('description', "libraryDescription")
            root.appendNode('name', "libraryName")
            root.appendNode('url', "siteUrl")
            root.children().last() + pomConfig
        }
```

also in the pomConfig you should use it like this:

```
def pomConfig = {
    licenses {
        license {
            name "licenseName"
            url "licenseUrl"
            distribution "repo"
        }
    }
    developers {
        developer {
            id "developerId"
            name "developerName"
            email "developerEmail"
        }
    }
    scm {
        url "gitUrl"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hi @matrix , I followed your aticle and using `gradlew bintrayUpload` I get : `Execution failed for task ':app:generatePomFileForMyPublicationPublication'  Could not apply withXml() to generated POM Could not get unknown property 'api' for configuration container`